# installed ubuntu on old laptop and wifi adapter doesn't work

Tags: drivers, wireless

Pretty common issue, I found many answers and could not figure it out (new linux user here and most things assume some background). Wifi worked while I was installing the OS. I opted for the LTS 20.04.2.0
I have Ethernet cable and connection is established.
I ran 'sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source' and got the following:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Reinstallation of bcmwl-kernel-source is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

I tried 'sudo apt install dkms' and got this:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
dkms is already the newest version (2.8.1-5ubuntu1).
dkms set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

I also checked if the adapter is soft or hard switched off, it wasn't. this must be a driver issue.

I pretty much just want to download the needed package and install it, but I have no clue how to know which one

Final note: I did notice that the .iso file had amd64 at the end and I am using an intel processor. Though I think that this is not the problem since wifi worked perfectly while installing the OS from a USB

Comment: Key to getting wifi to work is learning about what chipset you're using; refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide/Devices  where that detail allows us to point you where you need to go (or allows you to use search engines to find the results yourself..)

Comment: thanks, i'll go through that link. I found this adapter info for now: description: Network controller
       product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries

Comment: FYI:   Intel created the IA64 architecture that they wanted the market to move to when they went from 32-bit i386 to 64-bit, but it was incompatible with older programs/systems (ie. you had to start again). AMD created the x86_64 architecture that was backwards-compatible & it sold in the marketplace, IA64 failed to sell & intel dropped it, and intel too adopted what was then known as *amd64* so even modern intel cpus use *amd64*

Comment: Sometimes it because NDIS is missing. look at https://wiki.debian.org/NdisWrapper

Comment: @guiverc this post seems to be old and contains some links not available anymore

Comment: Searching on "BCM4313 ndis driver" may be useful

Comment: @guiverc about "Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers". I am apparently case#1. still working on it and will come back

Comment: @guiverc I got to "Special Case #1 - Uses bcma and brcmsmac driver combination. " I don't know what that means. is it "sudo apt install bcma"?

Comment: oh nvm, i rebooted and it worked! thanks alot. the " Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers " was the solution